# Using fgrep to find multiple words (korn shell)

Tags: regex, shell, ksh, grep

Say I have a text file with multiple lines, but I only want fgrep to list those lines which have certain words in the same line.  So, for example, if I'm looking for the words "cat" and "dog", how would I supply that information to fgrep?

I understand for one argument it would simply be:

```
    fgrep cat text.txt
```

but I want to look for lines that contain "dog" as well as "cat" in the same line.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Use `egrep` not `fgrep` and give it the appropriate regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
fgrep cat text.txt | fgrep dog
```

You can also use one regex with `grep -E`, something like:

```
grep -E "cat.*?dog|dog.*?cat" text.txt
```

But it is typically too much of brainpower to spend for simple task like that, and I choose first method instead.

Comment: Thank you!  I was guessing it had something to do with pipes.